# multiple form generated jquery doesn't submit

Tags: html, jquery, django, forms

I'm building a website (e-commerce like) with Django.

At some point I display a list of items and for each item there is a form with submit button Order and Quantity picker.

**I've implemented filter function that delete the html code of my items list and rebuild it with the matching items with jquery.**

**The new forms generated by this function do nothing when the submit button is clicked**

Here is a part of the code I use in my function (I use an ajax call to generate a json of matching items and then I display them in the table list) :

```
$.each(code_json, function(index, value){
                var string = "<tr id="+ value.material +"><td>"+ value.manufNo +"</td><form method='POST' action='/add_to_cart/"+value.material+"/"+ value.node+"/{{language}}'><td><input type='submit' class='btn' value='Commander' style='color:blue;'></td><td><input id='qty' type='number' name='qty' class='form-control' value='1'></td></form></tr>";
                $("#header").after(string);
                });
```

I know that usually with Django you have to add **{% csrf_token %}** for each form. However it throw an error page usually when missing and here it doesn't show anything

**Edit :** I tried to bind an onclick event on the submit button dynamically created. **In this I did a $.post in jquery to simulate the submit of the form but nothing happend**

```
$(document).on('click', '.btnStandard', function(event) {
        console.log($(this).attr('id'));
        $.post('/add_to_cart/'+$(this).attr('id'),
        {
            qty: $("#qty"+$(this).attr('id')).val()
        },function(data,status,xhr){
            alert("Data : "+data+", status: "+status+", xhr: "+xhr);
        });
```

It print in console $(this).attr('id') but it doesn't do anything else
Thank you for your help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamic form not submitting (jQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23330960/dynamic-form-not-submitting-jquery)

Comment: Thank you but I don't use javascript for for the submit ... I just use the action field in form tag. I would like not to complicate it overstep.

Comment: The issue remains the same afaik. I am quite sure that you **have to** do it for dynamically added forms, weather you want to or not.

Comment: Ok I will give a try tomorrow and let u know thanks

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work for me and by reading the post, it wasn't the solution OP used to solve his problem

Comment: Dynamically added forms will not submit the data as you expect them to do they can only submit the inputs that were present during load - in your case none at all. Thats why it works when you add them as a template and then use css to hide / show them. Simply adding something like `$('body').on('submit', '.myDynamicFormClass', function(){//do the submit here});` would suffice

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't explain why I have this problem but I found a workaround to solve my problem.

Instead of dynamically generate forms, I generate them with template and then I hide them all. Later, I make those I need visible when I need thanks to css.